# Looking for a javascript to coffeescript online converter

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

[js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org) seems to be "down". Does anyone know of any other online tool to convert javascript to coffee script?

Comment: http://js2coffee.org/ is up again

Comment: it was never down, but there is no converter there any more!

Comment: Oh! I had a cached version of the site. Doing Ctrl+F5 and now it is not there anymore

Comment: you shouldnt have done that :P

Comment: http://js2.coffee is the best :)

Comment: The site is broken... nothing works.

Comment: Up and working well now.

Comment: Nothing happens when I put in input on that site - the JS side remains empty, though it appears to try to "run" the code, somehow (no output).  Both links below are dead.  The one that used to work from the haml/html converter site is also now dead.  The so-called "ot" posts are some of the most helpful on this site, usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new converter, [Priest](http://priest.meteor.com/), helps you convert whole projects and does it securely in your browser.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://js2cs.nodejitsu.com/ ? I haven't used it much, but it looks decent.

Comment: Down. [ignore this, defeating the *#($& character minimum]

Answer (score 2):

You can also install `js2coffee` in node and run it from the command line. From their website:

`npm install js2coffee
js2coffee file.js > file.coffee`

This might be a good, temporary alternative if the site is down.

Comment: I think he wanted coffee TO js, not js TO coffee

Comment: @Kayvar OP mentions `js2coffee` in their question and mentions "Does anyone know of any other online tool to convert javascript to coffee script?".

Comment: Good point! You got it right

Comment: Sadly j2coffee doesn't compile current Javascript (e.g. `class`). Is there another tool around that works in 2016?

Comment: @Richard sorry, I left CoffeeScript behind more than a year ago. This solution is really intended to be a backup if `js2coffee.org` is down. You can always hand-edit the generated code.